Showing or hiding layer based on zoom level in Leafmap
I want to hide certain layers and show others as a user zooms into a Leafmap map in a Jupyter Lab notebook. This functionality seems possible in other libraries, but I can't figure out how it might be done in Leafmap.
Is it possible? This question is similar to this question (Leaflet layers on different zoom levels. How?) or this library.
I've tried a max_zoom style but it does nothing:
import leafmap
map = leafmap.Map(center=(12, 132), zoom=10, height="600px")
markers = "points.gpkg"
markers_style = {
    "max_zoom": 12
}
map.add_vector(markers, layer_name="Study Locations", style=markers_style)
map


Looks like the max zoom needs to be part of the layer properties not the style properties. With styles you would need to change style properties based in zoom level to show/hide/amend the layer rendering

Did you try nesting min_zoom and max_zoom directly in the add_vector(...) method ?

I did. That also does nothing.
